# Ordered sequence of even products of nonnegative integers and possible code

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, parity

I am trying to find the sequence  of the even products of nonnegative integers, m and n, after sorting them. For example, $$1*6=6, 2*3=6, 6*1=6, 3*2= 6$$
What I think is the answer is the sequence is just the even numbers in order repeated by the number of divisors of $2n$. I am having a problem figuring out why this is true. I just personally find it easier to write software than to think mathematically. And I would like help formally understanding if this is true and why it is true if it is true.

This problem arose because I was doing a simulation of the 2-player card game War with a deck with $m-suits$ and $n-values$. But generating the allowed $m$ and $n$ that gives a deck that can be divided evenly isn't easy, and I had to check to see if $mn$ was even.

So, playing around with Mathematica and this on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A099777), I think I found 2 software programs that both calculate the sequence of ordered products of nonnegative integers.

The functions are:

```
createSortedEvenProducts1[n_]:=(allCombinations=Flatten[Table[Table[{i,j,i*j},{i,1,2*n}],{j,1,2*n}],1];evenProductCombinations={};Table[If[EvenQ[allCombinations[[i,3]]]==True,AppendTo[evenProductCombinations,allCombinations[[i]]],None],{i,1,Length[allCombinations]}];sortedEvenProducts=Take[Map[Last,SortBy[evenProductCombinations, N@*Last]],Length[Flatten[Table[Table[2n,{i,1,DivisorSigma[0,2 j]}],{j,1,n}]]]])
```

and

```
createSortedEvenProducts2[n_]:=Flatten[Table[Table[2*j,{i,1,DivisorSigma[0,2 *j]}],{j,1,n}]];
```

Both `createSortedEvenProducts1[10]` and `createSortedEvenProducts2[10]` give:

`{2,2,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,8,8,8,8,10,10,10,10,12,12,12,12,12,12,14,14,14,14,16,16,16,16,16,18,18,18,18,18,18,20,20,20,20,20,20}`.

Comment: I recommend that you ask this question over on the [Mathematica sister site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @SammyBlack I had thought about that. But it is a question about mathematics, and not about using the Mathematica programming language. I just happened to use Mathematica. So, I don't know if it would be appropriate to post it on there.

Comment: Can you edit your post to make the mathematical question more clear?

Comment: @SammyBlack I did my best. If you have any more suggestions for improvement, feel free to tell me. I hope it is more understandable now. I am trying to submit my sequence on OEIS. But they do not allow for conjectured programs. But I have a feeling that the programs give the correct values. But I don't know how to argue why.

Comment: Maybe it is because of the edits you made, but it clear to me that your question belongs here, not the Mathematica forum, for exactly the reason you gave. The question is about math, not how to do something in Mathematica. There are a couple questions about the programs at the end, and those would be better asked in the Mathematica forum, but the main question is about mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say, it is a little hard for me to figure out how you can doubt your conclusion, as it seems obvious to me. But different people have different strengths, so here we go:

> What I think is the answer is the sequence is just the even numbers in order repeated by the number of divisors of $2n$.

First of all, it is restricted to positive even integers by your choice. Every integer is the product of itself and $1$, so every positive even integer must have an entry in your list. So it consists of all the positive even integers. And again, they are sorted by your choice. So it is a list of all the positive even integers in order.

Now for a given even integer $k > 0$, the number of repetitions of $k$ is the list will be the number of distinct ways that $k$ can be expressed as a product of a pair $(a,b)$ of positive integers: $k = a\times b$. But if $k = a \times b$ and $k = a \times c$, then $b = \frac ka = c$, so $b$ and $c$ are the same. That is, each pair is completely determined by $a$ alone. So what $a$ are possible? The condition that there is a $b$ such that $a \times b = k$ is exactly the definition of "$a$ is a divisor of $k$". So the set of all $a$ in the pairs is the exactly the set of divisors of $k$. There will be as many repetitions of $k$ in your list as $k$ has divisors.

Note that there is nothing peculiar to even integers here. The same statement, other than the "even" - would be true if you looked at all positive integers, or if you looked at positive odd integers, or some other set of postive integers. If you replaced "positive" with "non-zero", it would still all be true (though you would get double the number of repetitions, as you've doubled the number of divisors).

But if you drop "non-zero", suddenly your list will have an infinite number of $0$ entries between the positives and the negatives, as all integers are divisors of $0$.

Comment: It wasn't so much that I doubted the conclusion. I just could not reason why they would be the same.